# Require() e include() no php

Tags: php

Estou começando uns projetos e tenho uma pequena dúvida quanto ao uso de include() e require(). No caso de eu ter um cabeçalho e um rodapé prontos em arquivos php, para eu chamá-los, eu devo usar include() ou require()? Há alguma diferença na rapidez do script ou algo assim?

Comment: opa, verei a resposta, muito obrigado!